# Is this redirecting to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I found this script on the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_Flac_to_Mp3#With_FFmpeg) which prefixes an `ffmpeg` command like this

```
< /dev/null ffmpeg -i "$a" -qscale:a 0 "${a[@]/%flac/mp3}"
```

I understand the ffmpeg command, it is the `< /dev/null` part.  Is it supposed to redirect the verbose output to `/dev/null/`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No... it is *reading* from `/dev/null`. `command < input` and `< input command` are equivalent.

(So are `> output command` and `command > output`, by the way.)

Comment: Well now I am more confused.  Why would it read from `/dev/null`, when it `/dev/null` only yields `EOF`.  Why not just use `EOF`?

Comment: Redirecting `stdin` from `/dev/null` is the easiest way to get an immediate EOF. How else would you do it?

Comment: @PhilipWales, what's _`EOF`_? Redirecting input from `/dev/null` makes sure every read returns nothing. Alternative, shorter but less efficient is `:|ffmpeg ...`

Comment: @PhilipWales Redirecting input to /dev/null seems overkill, but it is a common technique to prevent the program from accidentally reading something from the keyboard buffer. E.g. say you have a program that will abort a lengthy operation if it receives an Escape from the keyboard. In most terminals Function-keys generate Escape-seqeuences... Reading from /dev/null will then prevent an unintended abort by a clumsy user pressing the wrong key by accident.

Comment: @Tonny: How is it overkill?

Comment: EOF: End Of File.

Comment: @KeithThompson In the sense that people just assume that it isn't necessary to redirect input when the program doesn't need input and thus this seems unneeded overkill. As I explained in the other comment sometimes you want to explicitly prevent input from happening.